# __init__() compared to __init__.py

Tags: python, filesystems, init

I am working on a game right now but I really hate having a few thousand lines to scroll through when finding a bug to fix or a new feature has stuffed up another function. I have kept everything in one main class and when I looked into writing each function into a different file, I had one problem, I couldn't find anything

```
class game:
def __init__( self ):
    self.foo = "Foo"
def function( self, bar ):
    self.bar = bar
```

so if we put it into a file system, it should look something like this

**game/**

- **__init__.py**
- **function.py**

and I do not know how to pass self or function into either init or funtion. Is there some sort of 
__brackets
__ =  ( self, bar ) code that will help me, or will I continue to have to scroll through heaps of code?

Comment: When breaking up a class, the goal is to break it up into multiple classes, not multiple files.

Comment: I don't think you can break a single class into multiple files

Comment: Lmao, that's pretty funny!!

Comment: You may want to rethink the basics of OOP if your entire game is stuffed into a single class..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong in my comment, you can do as you describe, but as @Ignacio stated its not good code design. Here's an example anyway because I was curious:

```
#Empty my_game 'class'
class my_game:
    pass

#Function you can put in a different file and import here
#Will become set as the new init function to 'my_game'
def my_games_init(self,x,y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y


#Assigning 'my_games_init' function to be used as init of 'my_game' class
my_game.__init__ = my_games_init

#Make a 'my_game' instance and show that it's x and y methods were set
g = my_game(1,2)
print g.x
print g.y
```

Comment: What you are doing there is called monkey patching. While it works it is horrible to debug when the project get more complex. Nobody can say where a method is defined from the perspective of the class.